# How to get these strings by using return instead of print?

Tags: python

For this question, I do not know what is wrong with the return usage here.

```
def createSteps(stepCount):
    if stepCount==1:
        for i in reversed(range(1,stepCount+1)):
            print(" "*(( i * 2) - 2), end = '')
            print('+-+')
            print(" " * ((i * 2) - 2), end = '')
            print('| |')
            print(" " * ((i * 2) - 2), end = '')
            print('+-+')
    elif stepCount != 0:
        print(" " * ((stepCount * 2) - 2), end = '')
        print('+-+')
   
        for i in reversed(range(1, stepCount + 1)):
            print(" " * ((i * 2) - 2), end = '')
            print('| |')
            print(" " * ((i * 2) - 4), end = '')
            if i == 1:
                print('+-+')
            else:
                print('+-+-+')
```

I tried to get the output by using return instead of using print,

```
for i in reversed(range(1,stepCount+1)):

    a = (" "*(( i * 2) - 2))
    b = ('+-+')
    c = (" " * ((i * 2) - 2))
    d = ('| |')
    e = (" " * ((i * 2) - 2))
    f = ('+-+')
    g = a + b + c + d + e + f
return str(g)
```

However, the error appears: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: You missed the indentation before `return`

Comment: You have to format the code you posted here better. Show the entire function. The first snippet has the if on at the same indent level as the function define, which means the if and loop are outside the function

Comment: I added the indentation, but it still appears the same error.

Comment: `return` only makes sense inside a function definition, which it isn't in the code you've shown. It needs to be in an indented block following a `def` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is inconsistent.  Your function must look like this.  Note that `g` is already a string, you don't have to convert it.  Also note that you will need to insert the newlines, since you are no longer using print to get that effect.

```
def createSteps(stepCount):
    g = []
    for i in range(stepCount,1,-1):
        a = " "*(( i * 2) - 2)
        b = '+-+'
        c = " " * ((i * 2) - 2)
        d = '| |'
        e = " " * ((i * 2) - 2)
        f = '+-+'
        g.extend( [a + b, c + d, e + f] )
    return '\n'.join(g)
```